# i need to use SELECT statment with UNION ALL several times (unknown no' times)

Tags: c#, union

i need to use SELECT statment with UNION ALL several times (unknown nomber times).
I did it with c# ! can i do it inside a stored procedure ?

### c#

```
// this code selects a number of users thoughts. for every user it is getting only 6 thoughts
// according to each user page number (friendsToughtPageNum).   
for (int i = startUser-1; i < endUser; i++){
     subSql += "SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP " + 6 * friendsToughtPageNum[i] + " * FROM (SELECT TOP  thought, firstName, lastName  FROM tbl_thoughts INNER JOIN tbl_users ON thoughtUserID = userID WHERE userID=" + IDs[i] + " ORDER BY thoughtID ASC) AS T" + i + " ORDER BY thoughtID DESC) AS TA" + i + " UNION ALL ";
                }
     subSql = subSql.Remove(subSql.Length - 11, 11);
     sql = subSql;
```

Comment: Why do you need `UNION`s? Can't you generate the `IN` clause instead using the `IDs` array?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it in a stored procedure by using a CURSOR and looping that way. You can then save the results to either a temp table and read from that or you can continue to use UNION ALL